# How to get/filter values in python3 json list dictionary response?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Below is result I got from API query.

```
[{'type':'book','title': 'example1', 'id': 12456, 'price': '8.20', 'qty': '12', 'status': 'available'},
 {'type':'book','title': 'example2', 'id': 12457, 'price': '10.50', 'qty': '5', 'status': 'none'}]
```

How do I specify in code to get value pairs of **title**, **price**, & **status** only?

So result will be like:

```
[{'title': 'example1', 'price': '8.20', 'status': 'available'},
 {'title': 'example2', 'price': '10.50', 'status': 'none'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension within a list comprehension:

```
L = [{'type':'book','title': 'example1', 'id': 12456, 'price': '8.20', 'qty': '12', 'status': 'available'},
     {'type':'book','title': 'example2', 'id': 12457, 'price': '10.50', 'qty': '5', 'status': 'none'}]

keys = ['title', 'price', 'status']
res = [{k: d[k] for k in keys} for d in L]

print(res)

[{'price': '8.20', 'status': 'available', 'title': 'example1'},
 {'price': '10.50', 'status': 'none', 'title': 'example2'}]
```